# Is THIS date within 1 year of todays date?

Tags: excel

How can I go about having a conditional formatting formula which checks the date in its cell and then formats it if the date is within 1 year from todays date?

I know I can do =EDATE(A5,16) which adds 16 months onto A5, but I don't know how to implement this into the above.

Comment: I suggest you use 12 instead of 16, seen as though a year is 12 months? :)

Comment: Sorry, was travelling ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to conditional formating, select the custom option and use this formula + select a formatting. Select the range you want to use it on.

```
=$H8<=EDATE(NOW();12)
*H being the column with dates*
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have Excel 2007 or later, in Excel 2003 or earlier versions EDATE cannot be used in conditional formatting. In any version you could use DATEDIF, e.g. this formula

`=DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"y")=0`

that will format A1 if the date in that cell is **>=TODAY** and **< TODAY + 1 year**

Answer (score 1):

**Can't you just do this:**

**Applied across your range:**
[image: ConditionalFormattingExample1]

**Using this formula:**
[image: ConditionalFormattingExample2]